# MySql/php utf8 doesn't seem to work right

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

So I have a table that is 'utf8_general_ci' with the same fields.

I couldn't get any utf8 characters into it, they all showed as '????' , then I changed table to 'MyISAM' and now I can insert utf8 data from PhpMyAdmin (first time something like this happens).

But it still doesn't work from PHP side. When I insert 'āāā' it shows as '???', but the weird part is if I insert 'žžžēēē' it show as 'žžž???' so some utf8 characters work?
PHP file is UTF-8

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `company` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

$dbConnection = mysql_connect("localhost","*****","*****");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $dbConnection);
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'", $dbConnection);
mysql_select_db('cherrysystem', $dbConnection);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `company` (`title`) VALUES ('āāčč')",$dbConnection);
```

**RESOLVED**

Ok, so problem in my case was that I had to set MySql ini file to use utf8.
By default it was something else, I'm using Wamp server and it have always worked without extra configuring, but not in this case.

```
 character-set-server=utf8
 collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: What about [`SET NAMES 'utf8'`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html)?

Comment: mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'",$dbConnection);

mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'", $dbConnection);

Comment: You know you can edit your question, right?

Comment: Did you create your table with `DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_yourLanguage_ci`? I had similar problem with my langauge and it helped.

Comment: I didn't set COLLATE , but i thought i takes db's default.
I just created your way and still the same problem.

Comment: This can have many reasons, most of them in your PHP script. Can you show how you insert the data and where it comes from?

Comment: Yes, I just updated my post. Its really simple script.

Comment: What character set is your PHP script saved in? Is it saved as UTF-8?

Comment: Yes file is saved as UTF-8, i have double checked this.

Comment: For anyone looking at this in 2017 and onwards: use mysqli_query, not mysql_query (note the "i"!) - for whatever reason that did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously something is not 'Unicode' in the way you handle the data.

Here are my top 7 usual suspects :

- PHP file containing the code is not UTF-8 itself
- Database connection must conform to Unicode (*SET NAMES 'utf8'*)
- Inserted data must be **utf8 encoded** if importing from a non unicode source e.g
- Check tables **and** the columns used to store data
- HTML file used to display the data is not UTF (same as point 1)
- HTML charset declared in `meta tags` must be utf-8 also
- ...  no point 7 (maybe in the comments)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi. So I triple checked everything.
PHP file is utf8.
As you can see in my top post I have SET NAMES 'utf8'.
I'm just inserting data from file, no other source.
I have checked all tables and they are utf8.
I`m running script from console, but dont see why HTML should change anything in db.

Comment: I know all the common problems and I have had them all before, but now  I have no idea.

Comment: @user1384210 : could you paste the html page and code you use to display this after the insert ?

Comment: I don't have any html page. I'm just using it from console (the exact script as in main post). And then looking in PhpMyAdmin for result.